# flex spark combobox

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I need to remove the spark combobox down arrow. I am able to do it mx component like this.

youcombobox instant.setStyle("arrowButtonWidth", 0);

How we can do it in spark comobobox ?

thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a custom skin that hides the openButton.  This is a required skin part, so you'll have to set it's visibility to false.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--

ADOBE SYSTEMS INCORPORATED
Copyright 2008 Adobe Systems Incorporated
All Rights Reserved.

NOTICE: Adobe permits you to use, modify, and distribute this file
in accordance with the terms of the license agreement accompanying it.

--> 
<!--- The default skin class for the Spark ComboBox component. 
The skin for the anchor button for a ComboBox component 
is defined by the ComboBoxButtonSkin class.  The skin for the text input
is defined by the ComboBoxTextInputSkin class.

@see spark.components.ComboBox        
@see spark.skins.spark.ComboBoxButtonSkin

@langversion 3.0
@playerversion Flash 10
@playerversion AIR 1.5
@productversion Flex 4
-->
<s:SparkSkin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
        xmlns:fb="http://ns.adobe.com/flashbuilder/2009" alpha.disabled=".5"> 

    <!-- host component -->
    <fx:Metadata>
        <![CDATA[ 
        /** 
        * @copy spark.skins.spark.ApplicationSkin#hostComponent
        */
        [HostComponent("spark.components.ComboBox")]
        ]]>
    </fx:Metadata> 

    <fx:Script fb:purpose="styling">
        <![CDATA[       
            private var paddingChanged:Boolean;
            private var cornerRadiusChanged:Boolean;
            private var cornerRadius:Number = 0;            

            /* Define the content fill items that should be colored by the "contentBackgroundColor" style. */
            static private const contentFill:Array = ["bgFill"];

            /**
             * @private
             */
            override public function get contentItems():Array {return contentFill};

            /**
             *  @private
             */
            override protected function commitProperties():void
            {
                super.commitProperties();

                if (paddingChanged && textInput)
                {
                    // Push padding styles into the textDisplay
                    var padding:Number;

                    padding = getStyle("paddingLeft");
                    if (textInput.getStyle("paddingLeft") != padding)
                        textInput.setStyle("paddingLeft", padding);

                    padding = getStyle("paddingTop");
                    if (textInput.getStyle("paddingTop") != padding)
                        textInput.setStyle("paddingTop", padding);

                    padding = getStyle("paddingRight");
                    if (textInput.getStyle("paddingRight") != padding)
                        textInput.setStyle("paddingRight", padding);

                    padding = getStyle("paddingBottom");
                    if (textInput.getStyle("paddingBottom") != padding)
                        textInput.setStyle("paddingBottom", padding);
                    paddingChanged = false;
                }

                if (cornerRadiusChanged)
                {
                    cornerRadiusChanged = false;

                    /* var cr:Number = getStyle("cornerRadius");

                    if (openButton)
                    openButton.setStyle("cornerRadius", cr);
                    if (textInput)
                    textInput.setStyle("cornerRadius", cr); */
                }
            }

            /**
             *  @private
             */
            override public function styleChanged(styleProp:String):void
            {
                var allStyles:Boolean = !styleProp || styleProp == "styleName";

                super.styleChanged(styleProp);

                if (allStyles || styleProp.indexOf("padding") == 0)
                {
                    paddingChanged = true;
                    invalidateProperties();
                }
                if (allStyles || styleProp == "cornerRadius")
                {
                    cornerRadiusChanged = true;
                    invalidateProperties();
                }                
            }

            /**
             * @private
             */
            override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
            {
                if (getStyle("borderVisible") == false)
                {
                    if (border)
                        border.visible = false;
                    if (background)
                    {
                        background.left = background.top = background.right = background.bottom = 0;
                    }
                    if (scroller)
                        scroller.minViewportInset = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (border)
                        border.visible = true;
                    if (background)
                    {
                        background.left = background.top = background.right = background.bottom = 1;
                    }
                    if (scroller)
                        scroller.minViewportInset = 1;
                }

                if (dropShadow)
                    dropShadow.visible = getStyle("dropShadowVisible");

                //openButton.setStyle("cornerRadius", getStyle("cornerRadius"));

                if (borderStroke)
                {
                    borderStroke.color = getStyle("borderColor");
                    borderStroke.alpha = getStyle("borderAlpha");
                }
                super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:states>
        <s:State name="normal" />
        <s:State name="open" />
        <s:State name="disabled" />
    </s:states>

    <!--- 
        The PopUpAnchor control that opens the drop-down list. 

        <p>In a custom skin class that uses transitions, set the 
        <code>itemDestructionPolicy</code> property to <code>none</code>.</p>
    -->
    <s:PopUpAnchor id="popUp"  displayPopUp.normal="false" displayPopUp.open="true" includeIn="open"
                   left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" itemDestructionPolicy="auto"
                   popUpPosition="below" popUpWidthMatchesAnchorWidth="true">

        <!--- 
            This includes borders, background colors, scrollers, and filters. 
            @copy spark.components.supportClasses.DropDownListBase#dropDown
        -->
        <s:Group id="dropDown">

            <!-- drop shadow -->
            <!--- @private -->
            <s:RectangularDropShadow id="dropShadow" blurX="20" blurY="20" alpha="0.45" distance="7" 
                                     angle="90" color="#000000" left="0" top="0" right="0" bottom="0"/>

            <!-- border -->
            <!--- @private -->
            <s:Rect id="border" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
                <s:stroke>
                    <!--- @private -->
                    <s:SolidColorStroke id="borderStroke" weight="1"/>
                </s:stroke>
            </s:Rect>

            <!-- fill -->
            <!--- Defines the appearance of drop-down list's background fill. -->
            <s:Rect id="background" left="1" right="1" top="1" bottom="1" >
                <s:fill>
                    <!---  
                        @private
                        The color of the drop down's background fill.
                        The default color is 0xFFFFFF.
                    -->
                    <s:SolidColor id="bgFill" color="0xFFFFFF" />
                </s:fill>
            </s:Rect>

            <!--- @private -->
            <s:Scroller id="scroller" left="0" top="0" right="0" bottom="0" hasFocusableChildren="false" minViewportInset="1">
                <!--- @copy spark.components.SkinnableDataContainer#dataGroup-->
                <s:DataGroup id="dataGroup" itemRenderer="spark.skins.spark.DefaultItemRenderer">
                    <s:layout>
                        <s:VerticalLayout gap="0" horizontalAlign="contentJustify" requestedMinRowCount="1" requestedMaxRowCount="6"/>
                    </s:layout>
                </s:DataGroup> 
            </s:Scroller>
        </s:Group>
    </s:PopUpAnchor>

    <!---  The default skin is ComboBoxButtonSkin. 
            @copy spark.components.supportClasses.DropDownListBase#openButton
            @see spark.skins.spark.ComboBoxButtonSkin -->
<!---- my only change is here ---->
        <s:Button id="openButton" width="19" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" focusEnabled="false"
                  skinClass="spark.skins.spark.ComboBoxButtonSkin" tabEnabled="false" visible="false" />  
        <!--- @copy spark.components.ComboBox#textInput -->
        <s:TextInput id="textInput" enabled.disabled="false"
                     left="0" right="18" top="0" bottom="0" 
                     skinClass="spark.skins.spark.ComboBoxTextInputSkin"/> 

    </s:SparkSkin>
```

Use it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <s:ComboBox skinClass="com.flextras.skins.ComboBoxNoDownArrow">
        <s:dataProvider>
            <mx:ArrayCollection>
                <fx:String>Flash</fx:String> 
                <fx:String>Director</fx:String> 
                <fx:String>Dreamweaver</fx:String> 
                <fx:String>ColdFusion</fx:String> 
                <fx:String>Flash</fx:String> 
                <fx:String>Director</fx:String> 
                <fx:String>Dreamweaver</fx:String> 
                <fx:String>ColdFusion</fx:String> 
                <fx:String>Flash</fx:String> 
                <fx:String>Director</fx:String> 
                <fx:String>Dreamweaver</fx:String> 
                <fx:String>ColdFusion</fx:String> 
            </mx:ArrayCollection>           
        </s:dataProvider>
    </s:ComboBox>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

You can probably tweak the skin more if needed; changing the "Right" value to 0 on the textInput, for example.   It took me more time to launch Flash Builder than it did to write the cod, so I suggest you read through [this documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS460ee381960520ad-2811830c121e9107ecb-7fff.html) as a reference on Skinning in the spark architecture works.

Comment: @flextras : I am trying this https://www.flextras.com/ free auto complete combobox. :) and need to remove this downarrow button. Do i have to follow the same steps with that ? I think you are the best person to answer.

Comment: Yes, you'll have to follow the same steps.  Create a custom skin and remove the down arrow.  I am pretty sure that the skin I posted in this answer should work w/ our AutoComplete.